# extracting numbers from string using regular expression

Tags: regex

I just encountered a problem in solving a regular expression at

http://regexone.com/lesson/13?

What the problem actually is, to provide a regular expression which takes out numbers in a text string. the sample string given is a screen resoluion like, 800X600 , 1024X768 etc.

We have to capture the numbers, such as 1024 in 1024X768
Anyone, who knows kindly inform me the solution as i have wasted half my day on solving it.

Comment: If you wasted so much time already...what have you tried? No need for us to waste the same time repeating your mistakes, is there?

Comment: show us what you tried so that we can correct you..also specify the language or tool you are using..

Comment: Dear Till, i am a newbie in regular expressions, and hence i have taken so much time in solving it, i hope it would be like a pie for the experts

Comment: (\d*[^x])
This expression i have used for solving, which is quite close, but does not match the full string, also you can click the regexone.com link which i have supplied in my question to see further details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for any number of digits followed by an x followed by any number of digits:

`(\d+)x(\d+)`

Comment: But i couldn't understand the syntax, can you plz explain, what i couldnt understand was the "x" in between is used when we gotta include it in the text, but the problem wanted to exclude x , and wanted to only include numbers such as 1024, 768 in the text "1024x768"

Comment: @user1834077 Its the parts in brackets that get extracted. Since the x is not in brackets it does not get extracted. It still needs to be there to be sure that it is matched.